# Horizontal line overlapping into two columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I would like to achieve something like in pic below:
[image]

The problem is in selected red line with rounded beginning. I used position:absolute, pseudoelements, but line always ending on the right column. And this should be responsive and have rounded beginning.
Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-md-6">
         <h3>heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-md-6">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. </p>
    </div>
</div>

.col-1,
.col-2 {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGrKae

Comment: The heading can be any size?

Comment: yes, any size, but reponsive

Comment: Thank you, this is a close solution. It seems to me that this will require a lot of media queries to keep rounded element at the appropriate position. What do you think about using the picture (line + rounded element) in pseudoelements?

Comment: This solution is close to perfection! One more point: the line overlaps under the right column, which means that it is not visible. I used Z-index: 999, but that gave nothing.

Comment: ok, I dealt with an z-index and now it works! great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-md-6">
         <h3>heading</h3>
    </div>
  <span class="line"><span></span></span>
    <div class="col-2 col-md-6">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. </p>
    </div>
</div>

.col-1, .col-2 {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
}

.line span {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  /* padding + border */
  top: 41px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 500px;
}
.line span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 11px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -10px;
}
```